# Is it possible to find out on which answer a deleted comment was left?

Tags: support, answers, comments

I have the Stack Overflow iPhone app installed and it notifies me whenever someone leaves a comment on one of my answers/questions.

Yesterday I got a notification that previewed a comment as, "What a stupid answer this is why....".  When I went to look at it, it was gone.  I assume it was quickly flagged and removed because of the tone.  But I'm still wondering about which answer of mine it was left on.

Is there any way for me to find which of my answers the comment was left on even though it's already gone?

Comment: It's gone. Better that way. No good reason to go digging after something like that.

Comment: To actually answer your question: I think that only moderators can see deleted comments. Although I don't _why_ a mod would oblige you. There is no compelling reason to go after such a comment (after it's been deleted). And "comments are ephemeral" and all that.

Comment: @yivi - I _think_ that with my 50k rep I can see deleted comments (but maybe that's just deleted answers?) but I don't know how to find the answer that it went to.  I'm not really interested in the comment, I'm just curious which of my answers prompted the response.

Comment: Nope, you can only see deleted posts

Comment: Ahh thanks for the clarification @rene

Comment: No, you can't see deleted comments. Only deleted posts. And curiosity doesn't seem a compelling enough reason to go after this. Nothing good may come of finding out which answer it was.

Comment: @yivi - glad you are here to make those decisions for me.

Comment: I went over the reported comments by Queen in [SOBOtics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=score&user=6294609&room=111347) but none of the reports of yesterday ended up on one of your answers. So either the word *stupid* is not enough to trigger the bot or your time range is off

Comment: @yivi: Some users might, beyond idle curiosity, want to report (patterns of) bad behavior that might have flown under the radar (perhaps as a direct consequence of the comment being silently deleted). I for one am curious now as to who the clown is that left Abe that lovely message...

Comment: @BoltClock Could be. But if the comment has already been deleted, and if there is no pattern (doing this repeatedly, to avoid being caught in the act), I see it as superfluous. The comment is gone, it is safe to assume that it could have been flagged; and if not the user already censored themselves. If it doesn't happen again... great. Nothing to see, nothing to flag. Everybody wins.

Comment: You haven't gotten a down vote on any of your answers recently so apparently the commentor didn't feel *that* strongly about it. That or they realized they were wrong before they voted and deleted the comment themselves. Either way, whichever answer it is probably doesn't actually have a problem.

Comment: @BSMP - I think there might also be a rep requirement to downvote.  Possible it was someone who doesn't use the site much.

Comment: True, there are 75 rep points between the comment privilege and the down vote privilege. Still, no one else has commented about a problem or down voted the same answer so I still think you're good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Not even moderators can see this easily — although we can view any user's responses tab (normally your own responses tab is visible to you and no one can see anyone else's), we can't see deleted comments there, and we have no way of viewing deleted comments addressed to a user from the addressed user's profile.

Without the name of the user who posted the comment (which IIRC appears in the notification, but in all likelihood you didn't take note of because it didn't seem important at the time), or a link to the post the comment was left on (which is what you're looking for to begin with), there's no practical way for us to trace the comment after it's been deleted unless the recipient happens to have few enough posts that we could probably just run through every one of them.